pgadmin SSL certificate error when performing maintence
When I use pgamin v4 8.11 to vacuum a table on a remote server not in my local network it fails with the error:

psql: error: connection to server at "xx.xxx.xx.xx", port 5432 failed:
SSL error: certificate verify failed connection to server at
"xx.xxx.xx.xx", port 5432 failed: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host
"12.345.678.90", user "postgres", database "dbname", no encryption

I am using ssl mode verify-full with an sslrootcert and passfile
I can query the same DB without issues.
Also, I can perform maintenance on another DB that is in server in my network.
My pg_hba.conf is
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
hostssl    all             all             12.345.678.90/24        scram-sha-256
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256

As suggested by jjanes, I checked the db's server logs.  They returned

2024-08-28 11:47:15.245 UTC [2462003] LOG:  could not accept SSL
connection: tlsv1 alert unknown ca 2024-08-28 11:47:15.290 UTC
[2462004] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "12.345.678.90", user
"postgres", database "dbname", no encryption

To test the ca I used this command
openssl s_client -starttls postgres -connect xx.xxx.xx.xx:5432 -CAfile /path/to/CAchain.pem

which returned

SSL handshake has read 4201 bytes and written 737 bytes Verification:
OK
--- New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 Server public key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE No ALPN negotiated Early data was not sent Verify
return code: 0 (ok) error:0A000126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected
eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:307:

The test connection string below works with a warning:
psql "postgresql://xx.xxx.xx.xx:5432/dbname?&sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=C:\path\CAchain.pem&user=postgres"


psql (16.0, server 15.8) WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from
Windows code page (1252)
8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
page "Notes for Windows users" for details. SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)

I was able to vacuum the table by opening a psql window from the pgamin window and entering the vacuum command manually.
My ability to test the connection with openssl and open psql from the command line as well as within pgamin and vacuum the table leads me to believe this is a bug in pgadmin.


Not clear to me whether the pg_hba.conf is from the local or remote server? 2) Did you set up the pgAdmin4 connection to use SSL?


The pg_hba.conf is from the remote server.  I set up the pgAdmin4 connection to use SSL in the parameters tab by setting sslmode to verify-full and providing a root certificate to match certificate specified in the server's postgresql.conf.

This failure occurs at the point you try to establish the connection.  At that point, it has no idea you are intending to issue a VACUUM once the connection is established, so it is hard to see how this intention could matter.

When you say "I can query the same DB without issues", is that query also happening in pgadmin from the same machine from which the other pgadmin attempt is failing? To the same dbname?  As the same username?

What exactly did you do to try to VACUUM the table from inside pgadmin?

jjanes, yes, the query is using pgadmin from the same machine to the same dbname with the same username.  To vacuum the table I right clicked on the table in pgadmin and selected maintenance from the menu.  I then clicked OK with the default vacuum settings.

I am at a loss for why your error message incorporates the label "psql:".  pgAdmin does outsource some actions to psql, but a VACUUM done the way you indicated should not be one of those things, so there is no reason for the error message to incorporate that label.  I can't get an error like that from my system even after intentionally breaking it.  What error message do you see in the database server's log file which corresponds to this connections failure?  Sometimes the server's half of the error is more informative than the client's half.

Thanks again jjanes.  I updated the question with the server logs.  This question also addressed an unknown ca.  https://serverfault.com/questions/793260/what-does-tlsv1-alert-unknown-ca-mean

Should I flag this question to have it moved to DBA StackExchange?  I've never posted a question there.
